# How to sort an array of objects by comparing different fields in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, object

So I found examples on how to sort arrays by comparing the same field, but I need to sort them by comparing different fields.  For example I have a lists of objects where each object has a field for their name and parent. I want to sort the list so that the people appear next to their parent.  Example:

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "parent": "Linda"
  },
  {
    "name": "Charlie",
    "parent": "Gregory"
  },
  {
    "name": "Linda",
    "parent": "Stacy"
  },
  {
    "name": "Andrew",
    "parent": "Gabriel"
  },
  {
    "name": "Gregory",
    "parent": "Thomas"
  }
]
```

After sorting I want Bob to be next to Linda and Charlie to be next to Gregory.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @poppo8989: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

*Suggestion: If you have control over the data presented in your question, you might consider storing it in a structure that better represents the relationships.*

Otherwise, here's a take on solving your problem:

[Explore code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwLACgopUBDAWwgC4pFh4BLVAcwG4CiwT4JVhraGzNvgC+wgqEhQAShAA2JYPTSIAFvTAARRSUw52UAMbq5AEwD81OEjTCOXHsEuwEKVMLEECAMwCuqQyU0KCYIYFkFINQ1DUQoAApIZDA5KhcbVABtAF0AGihIDKtXNABKagjFZWj1LR19QihuYF94dDxGomN6M2oklIgAOm9GU0TMAD4Cwc5uXkwMLEK3QdIKUtyDezm+Aohk1OHR8YwpsFXyaEWlktQZh14Ng09RL3w-AKiQsIBlZHhgBBTHADtBEvsBsUMjlyuk3DkGl0VMAaP9AaYofDsnocnYjMj8WAQDjBqT+qlsuJGgB3ExgwzJECDVLMYCqKBTAAMpURRCgqRRyzQmOCAB8oP5TBARqggXoGUTMpzKVt+WEoKY0FcoN4SHJEBAqXyoAB6E00dVC9DAZA61psiC0KAkAKOm3wVW0npgq1QABkfqgAEJNbKeR1jUjoijsLNHCI9KFwvIqipaoh4gqQPkraU8cb6N4EnHHnsMnoS8B83z5AaNVq9HRfIbVSI3sazU0IGRkAA3aDeeDIMiE4lceAkMeoUzO0wzm2ogFy8eT-LcSCKIFyYnef5QCAkYxGEymT104u3cOqpFEwaIFL0QwQTOMwajCAADwA8t5wRkNlAACMebXou6IzL4ah-m4IGdHyvpYEmlRRDEYAZlmOaXoM3RmNWbaNPhBjNK06AoEupgeG8HyBNUUBkCQjAJFejQMtGeygiKWTYlgmSqtgaxpAA5AAQsgABGgk5g8uyCQAMqMJCCSImxwfxlzUIJADCqhcHI9AQJJBTSRpADi3BMP8IBKSpxpqRQGnydOilSTsGk-MAh5WcpfECRpACC07cNShmVqZJBiQw8jWT56lQIJZkQBZ8BWS5jgaQAKqow4kIg0WNCq+AGKxTpkeiia-GiQIggM4KgrBUYoIccjIEw8SlUCeamiapxQI5pgkPkolifkCVJdmUDabp+n5AFphBQQhH4PRjDxHmQA)

```ts
type Person = {
  name: string;
  parent: string;
};

type RelationshipData = {
  child?: Person;
  parent?: Person;
};

function getRelationships (people: Person[], person: Person): RelationshipData {
  return {
    child: people.find(p => p.parent === person.name),
    parent: people.find(p => p.name === person.parent),
  };
}

function getSortedPeople (people: Person[]): Person[] {
  const sorted: Person[] = [];
  const copy = [...people];

  while (copy.length > 0) {
    let person: Person | undefined = copy[0];
    let done = false;

    // set person to furthest ancestor
    while (person && !done) {
      const {parent} = getRelationships(copy, person);
      if (parent) person = parent;
      else done = true;
    }

    // remove from copy array and add to sorted array, repeatedly for each child
    while (person) {
      copy.splice(copy.indexOf(person), 1);
      sorted.push(person);
      person = getRelationships(copy, person).child;
    }
  }

  return sorted;
}

function main () {
  const people: Person[] = [
    {name: 'Bob', parent: 'Linda'},
    {name: 'Charlie', parent: 'Gregory'},
    {name: 'Linda', parent: 'Stacy'},
    {name: 'Andrew', parent: 'Gabriel'},
    {name: 'Gregory', parent: 'Thomas'},
  ];

  const sorted = getSortedPeople(people);
  console.log(sorted); //=> Linda, Bob, Gregory, Charlie, Andrew
}

main();
```